# When is stack AP better than Magic Penetration

Tags: league-of-legends

When (or "why") is it better purchasing Void Staff instead of a second Rabadon's Deathcap? Without the passive, Rabadon's Deathcap gives 120 AP! I think It's more than the Magic Resistance of most kinds of champions (with the exception of tanks).

Comment: Buying two (or more) of the same item with UNIQUE effects won't cut it. (Not even in normal)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally I think getting a second rabadons is a bad choice. There are other items that give a lot of AP (close to 120) plus you get lots of other stuff as well (for example Deathfire Grasp which gives you 100 AP and 15% cooldown reduction and a great active which is like one extra spell). The reason rabadons is so great is not the 120 ap. It's the passive.

So in my opinion you don't have to get into the whole magic resistance vs magic penetration calculation.

If your dilemma is Second Rabadons vs Void Staff - Just go Void Staff.

But if you want a truly damage based comparison overlooking every other aspect of the game lets do some math using this website: http://idunnolol.com/lol/calculator.html

If you have

> Base magic damage - 300
>
> AP    - 120 (Rabadons)
>
> AP Scaling - 1.8
>
> Spell Cooldown (secs) - 5
>
> Magic Resistance - 100

You will get

> Damage on hit - 258

with void staff you got 35% magic pen so you get 65 magic resist and 70 ap 
so you have

> Base magic damage - 300
>
> AP    - 70 (void staff)
>
> AP Scaling - 1.8
>
> Spell Cooldown (secs) - 5
>
> Magic Resistance - 65

and you get

> Damage on hit - 258.1818181818182

So its even when the opponent has 100 magic resist. 
If he has more magic resist void staff beats rabadons
if he has less rabadons beats void staff

also if your spell has more Ap Ratio than 1.8 Rabadons wins
if your spell has less Ap Ratio Void Staff Wins.

You can do the math for any spell you want. But if you dont need void staff then I still insist you get something else instead of Rabadons.

Comment: Added note: Magic penetration is far more valuable for certain champions such as Elise whose damage scales to health percentage while having low AP ratios. For these champions, you might go with a Void Staff before even touching a Rabadon's.

Comment: @Yawus Exactly! Like I said above: If your spells have less Ap Ratio Void  Staff wins. Another example would probably be ryze (not sure though) who scales with mana.

Comment: You have to think that there is some abilities that have AP ratios but not necesseraly only damages : likes Heals(Nida/Yi/....) or Shield(Sion/Diana/Oriana/...) but most of the time you want to have a lot of penetration for the champions with low ratios ;-). And now that  % penetration is applied before flat penetration, void staff has become realy Realy REALY good item :-D.

Comment: @Hystic yes for champions with heals and shields etc flat ap would be better than magic pen. But still a second rabadon's seems like the worst choice even if thats the case. You can get 100 ap from Deathfire's grasp and you also get Cooldown reduction and a nice extra damage source. 
Or any other high AP item would be nice. The extra 20ap is just not worth losing all those nice extra goodies you would get from another item. Plus if your goal is to play Ultra Glass Cannon why not just stack Archangel's staffs and a rabadons...That would give you much more AP than stacking rabadons...

Comment: I agree ;-) stacking same items is for me the worst idea ever ^^. just pointing the choice beetween AP flat and magic Pen But personaly i prefer Zhonya to DFG cause a dead champion do no damage :-D

Answer (score -1):

I always laugh when I see people with 2 rabadons. I think zhonyas gives 120 AP & death fire grasp also. Even if they give 20 less AP who cares with the actives they are worth losing 20 AP. Also archangels staff gives about 170 AP, so just stack that tear. ^^